# "Invalid package information" error when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 19.10, 20.04

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04 but when I run the update, in the second stage this error pops:

> **Invalid package information**
>
> After updating your package information, the essential package 'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list for the current list of configured software sources.
> In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade again later.

Comment: [I reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1897799) this bug, user [Brian Murray](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BrianMurray) set it as duplicate of [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1813354). If this affects you, consider saying so there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution was to add the official sources to the apt sources.list.

1. Make a copy of your source list:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
   ```
2. Get the official sources for Ubuntu 19.10 from [sources.list › Wiki › ubuntuusers.de](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/sources.list/#Eoan)

   ```
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   ```
3. Open the list and add these lines at the end

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
4. Update sources and install all available updates for 19.10 and reboot your system:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo reboot
   ```
5. Ensure you have the lts path at the update-manager:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
   Prompt=lts
   ```
6. If you upgrade over ssh: ensure your firewall allows ssh access over port 1022 (recovery-ssh-port). I didn't need to use port, it is just in case.
7. Run the Upgrade

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

Comment: This is using a German mirror of the Ubuntu sources. While it may work, it is not a general solution.

Answer (score 58):

The actual solution is to run `RELEASE_UPGRADER_ALLOW_THIRD_PARTY=1 do-release-upgrade` instead of the normal upgrade command.

There's no need to manually mess with `sources.list` (which doesn't work anyway). Just prevent the OS from disabling third-party sources, because they include packages that the OS needs in order to complete the upgrade.

Source: a comment in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cannot-update-to-19-04-the-essential-package-ubuntu-minimal-could-not-be-located-2

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me while doing 18.04 LTS to 20.04 @DigitalOcean.

Comment: ah yes. some hosts have their own local repository for optimization, and remove the canonical repository. When the do-release-update disables the "3rd party", its actually cutting off the core source.

Comment: @cucu8 - same. The `RELEASE_UPGRADER_ALLOW_THIRD_PARTY=1` env variable got it to work for me as well.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this problem on a DigitalOcean droplet. The fix from [VivienM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cannot-update-to-19-04-the-essential-package-ubuntu-minimal-could-not-be-located-2?answer=51260) seems to have done the trick for me.

> While do-release-update was paused at this message:
>
> ```
> Third party sources disabled
>
> Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can
> re-enable them after the upgrade with the ‘software-properties’ tool
> or your package manager.
>
> To continue please press [ENTER]
> ```

After you see this message go to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and uncomment all the references to `mirrors.digitalocean.com`. Then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to resume the installation.

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

This sorted it for me. It seems the automatic source.list relying on mirrors.txt functionality did not work for some reason. What comes to the archive mirror list above, the URL is:

```
http://<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

Comment: That's a wonderful URL. How is it a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In my case both `RELEASE_UPGRADER_ALLOW_THIRD_PARTY=1 do-release-upgrade` and `do-release-upgrade --allow-third-party` didn't work.

I had to manually convert the entries from `/etc/apt/source.list` file from

`deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted`

to real repo URL like

`deb http://ubuntu.task.gda.pl/ubuntu focal main restricted`

You need to run `sudo apt-get update` after the change.

Then I was able to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 without any errors.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! You saved my day :-)
I rather used "http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/" url, got it from another server of mine. But yeah, the mirror url doesn't seem to work properly...

Comment: For me, to update from 20.04 to 22.04, I manually add URLs from the 22.04 version of [/etc/apt/sources.list](https://gist.github.com/hakerdefo/9c99e140f543b5089e32176fe8721f5f) into my local version.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue when upgrading 16.04 to 18.04.

It started upgrading when I added these lines to my `sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main universe multiverse
```

See also https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17813/errors-when-upgrading-from-1604-to-1804#answer-68979

Comment: This is unrelated (please read the other answers, namely the accepted one) and not applicable to the actual question. Ubuntu 16.04 is out of support for a long time now.