# Belated upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I have a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu Server 16.04. I tried to run a `do-release-upgrade` (after the mandatory `apt update` and `apt upgrade`) but it stops fairly quickly:

```
Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                   
Get:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security InRelease [7476 B]                                                                                            
Get:2 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates InRelease [7475 B]                                                                                             
Get:3 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                                                                                
Get:4 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                                                                                              
Get:5 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]                                                                                               
Get:6 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [2048 kB]                                                                                     
Get:7 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [1524 kB]                                                                                      
Get:8 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1220 kB]                                                                                 
Get:9 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [1086 kB]                                                                                  
Fetched 6218 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                 
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

Get:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security InRelease [7458 B]                                                                                            
Get:2 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-updates InRelease [7457 B]                                                                                             
Fetched 14.9 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                 

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Invalid package information 

After updating your package information, the essential package 
'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have 
no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of 
excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list 
for the current list of configured software sources. 
In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade 
again later.
```

Is this because the software sources are no longer correct (if so what would be the correct ones)? The official DO mantra is to install a fresh version on another droplet and then switch droplets but I want to avoid this.

Edit: The standard `/etc/apt/source.lst` on DO points only to DO's mirrors. Peeking at it (before `do-release-upgrade` restores it due to failure), it appears that all entries are commented out (considered as 3rd party sources?). So where can I find a sources.lst that points to the Canonical repos?

Bonus points for a method to move to 20.04 without the 18.04 step...

PS: the `do-release-upgrade` on my other droplet running 18.04 worked flawlessly.

Comment: @user535733 Please see edited question

Comment: Maybe 16.04 is no longer in that repo? Try the Ubuntu Archive

Comment: Looks like your problem is that `do-release-upgrade` is not designed for migration from an ESM system. Your sources were changed to invalid/non-existent bionic-ESM, which causes the upgrade to fail. The correct answer is to clean-install 20.04, since you missed the upgrade window (sorry). If you want to haywire `do-release-upgrade` into working, you must manually edit your sources to a [non-ESM repo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories). It might work, it might not -- that's why it's haywiring.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you are using Digital Ocean. Make a snapshot, then you can try replacing the source.list with the archived versions like so

`sudo sed -i 's/mirrors.digitalocean.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list`

then try running `do-release-upgrade` again.

If hitting a snag, I also had to run this before `do-release-upgrade`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Once finished, revert the file back.

`sudo sed -i 's/us.archive.ubuntu.com/mirrors.digitalocean.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

Adding these sources worked for me:
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/sources.list/#Eoan

Following this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1242258

It worked with ease.